# See if a any of a list of users, is a member of an AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have a list of Users and a list of AD Groups. I would like to know, if any of the users are a member of those groups.

- I do not need to know which members are a member of which group.
- I just need to know if ANY user matches a Group, if a match exists
  output Match found and group name.

I have got this code:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\test\testusers.csv
$groups = Get-Contect C:\test\testgroups.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive |
                   Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
        if ($members -contains $user) {
            Write-Host "Match Found $group"
        }
    }
}
```

I have run this against a test of 4 users and 3 ad groups, whilst this gives me what I need. I get the output:

- Match Found Groupname 1
- Match Found Groupname 2
- Match Found Groupname 1

My understanding is that this is scanning each user against all groups, then the next user against all groups. Whilst this worked for my test batch in small numbers, I need to scan 2000 users against 1100 groups.

I take it this is because I am scanning the users against groups? and need to scan groups for users?

Is there a way I can put a line of code that says, if found move to next group?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there away i can put a line of code that says, if found move to next group?

Yes, you can use the `break` key word, to break a `foreach` loop.

However, I suggest to solve your requirement diffently.

> I just need to know if ANY user matches a Group, if a match exists output Match found and group name.

More efficient then breaking after the first match, is to always query a group once. There are different options. One option would be to use `Compare-Object` to find names that are member of a group and part of your input CSV, which is exactly what you call a match.

```
$users = Get-Content C:\test\testusers.csv
$groups = Get-Content C:\test\testgroups.csv

foreach ($group in $groups) {

    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive

    if (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $members.SamAccountName -DifferenceObject $users -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual) {
        $group
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer. Spelling in the second line of code needs checking, though: Get-Contect.

Comment: @Jordan thanks for noting. I copied that from the original code :D